# RequireJS load my JS files, but trigger an error when using them

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm stuck here for 2 days now, and I really hope you can help me.

I'm trying to use this theme I bougth on wrapbootstrap ( https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/ace-responsive-admin-template-WB0B30DGR ) with backboneJS and requireJS

So, basically, I have this file structure for the exemple :

```
index.html
app/
 |___ js/
 |____ main.js
assets/
 |___ js
       |___ ace.min.js
       |___ ace-extra.min.js
       |___ ace-elements.min.js
       |___ bootstrap.min.js
       |___ jquery.min.js
libs
 |___ require
       |___ require.js
```

So, when I use this basic template :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Blank Page - Ace Admin</title>

    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!--basic styles-->

    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    <!--[if IE 7]>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css" />
            <![endif]-->

    <!--page specific plugin styles-->

    <!--fonts-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace-fonts.css" />

    <!--ace styles-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace-responsive.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace-skins.min.css" />

    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace-ie.min.css" />
            <![endif]-->

    <!--inline styles related to this page-->

    <!--ace settings handler-->

    <script src="assets/js/ace-extra.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <!--basic scripts-->

    <script src='assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--page specific plugin scripts-->

    <!--ace scripts-->

    <script src="assets/js/ace-elements.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/ace.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

No errors, all work perfectly. Then, I want, to load all the script

1. ace-extra.min.js
2. jquery.min.js
3. bootstrap.min.js
4. ace-elements.min.js
5. ace.min.js

In this order, juste like the template.

So, I add this line in the head

```
<script async data-main="app/main" src="libs/require/require.js"></script>
```

and created the main.js like this :

```
require.config({
    // The shim config allows us to configure dependencies for
    // scripts that do not call define() to register a module
    shim: {
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        ace: {
            deps: ['aceElement']
        },
        aceElement: {
            deps: ['aceExtra', 'bootstrap', 'jquery']
        }
    },
    paths: {
        jquery: '../assets/js/uncompressed/jquery-2.0.3',
        bootstrap: '../assets/js/uncompressed/bootstrap',
        ace: '../assets/js/uncompressed/ace',
        aceExtra: '../assets/js/uncompressed/ace-extra',
        aceElement: '../assets/js/uncompressed/ace-elements'
    }
});
require([
    'jquery',
    'bootstrap',
    'ace'
], function() {

});
```

and I remove all the scripts, so I have this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Blank Page - Ace Admin</title>

        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <!--basic styles-->

        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

        <!--[if IE 7]>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css" />
        <![endif]-->

        <!--page specific plugin styles-->

        <!--fonts-->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace-fonts.css" />

        <!--ace styles-->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace-responsive.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace-skins.min.css" />

        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace-ie.min.css" />
        <![endif]-->

        <!--inline styles related to this page-->

        <!--ace settings handler-->
    <script async data-main="app/main" src="libs/require/require.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
              ...
    </body>
</html>
```

but here, I have an error

```
     Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'handle_side_menu'
```

comes from here :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    //ace.click_event defined in ace-elements.js
    ace.handle_side_menu(jQuery);

    ace.enable_search_ahead(jQuery);    

    ace.general_things(jQuery);//and settings

    ace.widget_boxes(jQuery);

    /**
    //make sidebar scrollbar when it is fixed and some parts of it is out of view
    //>> you should include jquery-ui and slimscroll javascript files in your file
    //>> you can call this function when sidebar is clicked to be fixed
    $('.nav-list').slimScroll({
        height: '400px',
        distance:0,
        size : '6px'
    });
    */
});
```

despite of this generated code, (Chrome dev tool) :

```
    <html lang="en"><head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Blank Page - Ace Admin</title>

        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!--basic styles-->

        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <!--[if IE 7]>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css" />
        <![endif]-->

        <!--page specific plugin styles-->

        <!--fonts-->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace-fonts.css">

        <!--ace styles-->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace-responsive.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace-skins.min.css">

        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ace-ie.min.css" />
        <![endif]-->

        <!--inline styles related to this page-->

        <!--ace settings handler-->
        <script async="" data-main="app/main" src="libs/require/require.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="main" src="app/main.js">
    </script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="jquery" src="app/../assets/js/uncompressed/jquery-2.0.3.js">
    </script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="bootstrap" src="app/../assets/js/uncompressed/bootstrap.js">
    </script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="aceExtra" src="app/../assets/js/uncompressed/ace-extra.js">
    </script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="aceElement" src="app/../assets/js/uncompressed/ace-elements.js">
    </script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="ace" src="app/../assets/js/uncompressed/ace.js">
    </script></head>

    <body style=""></body></html>
```

So, I really don't understand, I would be really happy if anyone have an answer.
Thansk !

Kai23

Comment: First, the data-main attribute should probably be data-main="app/js/main" given your structure. Second, what does your main.js file look like?  How are you requesting the files through require?

Comment: thanks, I totally forgot to include it.

Comment: So, where does the code that has ace.handle_side_menu live? Usually with require, you'd define a module or at least dependencies by using the `require()` function (e.g. `require(['ace', 'aceExtra', 'jquery'], function(ace, extra, $) { /* Do stuff */ })`)

Comment: Your shims don't have any exports.

Comment: @legacybass it's in ace.js. I've set-up a repository on github, temporarily : https://github.com/kai23/ace-require
Gaurav : are the exports required ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it turns out it's the order in which you are doing things in the ace.min.js file.  To fix it, just move your second jQuery function which contains the `ace.handle_side_menu` to the bottom of your ace.min.js file.  It is a bit of a coincidence, but here's why.

When require loads your main.js file, it starts asynchronously loading your js files.  This gives the rest of the page and DOM a chance to load (which is precisely why we like require.js).  By the time your ace.min.js file gets loaded, the window has already signalled the `onReady` event.  So, in your ace file where you have

```
jQuery(function($) {
    ace.handle_side_menu(jQuery);
```

jQuery immediately realizes the DOM is ready and immediately calls the function you're passing in (the `function($)` part).  This function then starts to run before `handle_side_menu` gets attached to the ace object.  If you use the Chrome debugger tools and place breakpoints on both places where you have `handle_side_menu`, you'll see that the one inside the jQuery callback gets hit first.

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem ! I've put these functions in the main.js, after that all is loaded. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

dude, it's a coincidence.
I used the same theme for my project, you can look into my html template:

https://github.com/pjyong/chenxi/blob/master/src/ChenXi/MainBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig

and my main JS file:

https://github.com/pjyong/chenxi/blob/master/web/app/js/main.js

If you have more questions, I will answer them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll sure have a look on your project settings, but I think that legacybass gave me the right answer.